# How to tell if a time range is within a time range? PHP

Tags: php, date, time, range

I have 2 employees who work in two timeblocks on monday.  I want to offer our clients an easy way to create an appointment broken down by segments of the day (Evening, afternoon, morning).

```
- Morning: 0001 to 1200
- Afternoon: 1201 to 1600
- Evening: 1601 to 2400
```

Monday through Friday's Schedule
John works: 7am to 1pm
Michael works: 1pm to 7pm

Saturday's Schedule
John works: 8am to 12pm

Mon - Fri should show the buttons for: Morning, Afternoon, and Evening.
Saturday should only show the Morning button.

I'm not sure how to make this happen, because John's schedule ends in the Afternoon.  So I'm figuring out how to check if a time range is within another time range and return a bool or something.

[image: http://screencloud.net/img/screenshots/123e673cdad3ea47337d512f6ef2fddc.png]

I was trying to break everything into start and end time blocks, which I got successfully.  However when it came time to compare them to the times of day (evening, afternoon, morning) I didn't know how to compare them.

I don't want to come off as trying to get you guys to write my code, I need help with the logic.  As you can see from the screenshot this is already all written up except for this small but big piece.
Any ideas would be much appreciated!

[SOLUTION]

I'm using the Laravel php framework's ORM called Eloquent. <3
* NOTE: doing range(1201, 1600, 5) messed things up and range(1200, 1600) would result in huge memory consumption so I incremented by 5.

```
                $day_segments = array(
                    "morning" => range(0, 1200, 5),
                    "afternoon" => range(1200, 1600, 5),
                    "evening" => range(1600, 2400, 5)
                );

                // On what days of the week are users working and in what time ranges?
                $user_timeranges = array();
                foreach ($record->users()->get() as $user) {
                    foreach ($user->timeblocks as $timeblock) {
                        $start_range = date('Hi', strtotime("{$timeblock->start_hour} {$timeblock->start_divide}"));
                        $end_range = date('Hi', strtotime("{$timeblock->end_hour} {$timeblock->end_divide}"));

                        $user_timeranges[$timeblock->day][] = range($start_range, $end_range, 5);
                    }
                }

                // On each day what day segments are available to create appointments?
                $available_segments = array();
                foreach ($days_available as $day) {
                    $available_segments[$day] = array();
                    foreach ($day_segments as $name => $segment) {
                        $available_segments[$day][$name] = 0;
                        foreach ($user_timeranges[$day] as $timerange) {
                            if (array_intersect($segment, $timerange)) {
                                $available_segments[$day][$name]++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                vardump($available_segments);
                exit;
```

Comment: Seems like you're asking us to do the work for you.

Comment: Please don't think that, I have everything laid out and my php is generating everything I'm having a hard time with the logic of this.  I don't need any code I just don't understand how to write this.

Comment: @Munchies I was trying to break everything into start and end time blocks, which I got successfully.  However when it came time to compare them to the times of day (evening, afternoon, morning) I didn't know how to compare them.

Comment: Why can't you use a database?

Comment: Seems like you already solved this, but in an SQL environment, if you have start and end times, you could just query for "Select * where X between start and end" and if you get any rows you know you've hit an intersect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to be going by full hours only, you could define each segment with the `range()` function, and similarly for each worker. Then use `array_intersect` and see if you get a thruthy result.

Example:

```
$times = Array("morning"=>range(0,12),"afternoon"=>range(12,16),"evening"=>range(16,24));
$people = Array("John"=>range(7,13),"Michael"=>range(13,19));
$available = Array();
foreach($times as $k=>$v) {
    $available[$k] = 0;
    foreach($people as $name=>$times) {
        if( array_intersect($v,$times)) $available[$k]++;
    }
}
var_dump($available);
```

Comment: Researching array_intersect() and trying this will report.